# Content is overflowing from the body

Tags: html, css, overflow, page-layout

I am facing an issue where the `content overflow out of the page`

I have tried adding the `with: 100%` to the `body, main` div but still the content is `overflowing` and I can see that issue in `mobile` view, I guess the same issue may happen in `Desktop` view as well currently its working fine on Desktop.

I created a page in which I have added a `form` and that form is overflowing from the `body`.

I have also tried adding the `border-box` css property for the layout of the page but the form is still overflowing.

Adding image for reference:

[image]

**Code Snippet**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.myAccount-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  .myAccount-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .account-img {
      img {
        width: auto;
        @media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 991px) {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    }

    .account-img,
    .account-form {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  }
}

// my account section
.profile-details {
  display: flex;
}

// form styling
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0px 0 0 15px;
}

.profile-name {
  position: relative;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
   <div id="root">
      <div class="wrapper">
         <main class="main-component">
            <div class="myAccount-wrapper">
               <div class="myAccount-section">
                  <div class="account-img"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScppAjzrG06w7v07vGUeT7E35MSS6Zfry2pEBrCYAxGRjtC7dNHz8JdB5rfJCh5FKaCjY&amp;usqp=CAU" alt="Profile"></div>
                  <div class="account-form">
                     <form>
                        <div class="account-header">
                           <h3 class="">MY ACCOUNT</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-name"><input type="text" class="inputText" required=""><span class="floating-label">Name</span></div>
                        <div class="profile-details">
                           <div class="profile-name"><input type="text" class="inputText" required=""><span class="floating-label">Mobile</span></div>
                           <div class="profile-name"><input type="text" class="inputText" required=""><span class="floating-label">Email</span></div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </main>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is your design online ? if so give its link

Comment: @AmirRahman actually I can't share the link for some reason

Comment: what is your desired look ? do you want each input in single line or 2 per line ?

Comment: What kind of behavior would you like to get? For example you can use flex-wrap: wrap; for .profile-details. Is it OK?

Comment: did you use SASS in your style? because it is not similar to CSS and you mentioned CSS in your tags.

Comment: @AmirRahman for Desktop: "Name" input will be in one row (full width) whereas "Mobile" and "Email" will be in one row with two input (50, 50 width as shared in image) 
for Mobile:  all the inputs will be in single line

Comment: @hamid-davodi   yes, I will be converting CSS into SCSS some of the code which I have written in CSS. Will update the tag to scss, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduce code above like that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   
    <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "segoe ui";
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.myAccount-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-img img {
  width: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-img img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-img,
.myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-form {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.profile-details {
  display: flex;
}

input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0px 0 0 15px;
}

.profile-name {
  position: relative;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  padding: 5px;
}
    </style>
</head>

 <body>
   <div id="root">
      <div class="wrapper">
         <main class="main-component">
            <div class="myAccount-wrapper">
               <div class="myAccount-section">
                  <div class="account-img"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScppAjzrG06w7v07vGUeT7E35MSS6Zfry2pEBrCYAxGRjtC7dNHz8JdB5rfJCh5FKaCjY&amp;usqp=CAU" alt="Profile"></div>
                  <div class="account-form">
                     <form>
                        <div class="account-header">
                           <h3 class="">MY ACCOUNT</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile-name"><input type="text" class="inputText" required=""><span class="floating-label">Name</span></div>
                        <div class="profile-details">
                           <div class="profile-name"><input type="text" class="inputText" required=""><span class="floating-label">Mobile</span></div>
                           <div class="profile-name"><input type="text" class="inputText" required=""><span class="floating-label">Email</span></div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </main>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I think you can use flex-wrap: wrap; for .profile-details.

Comment: Yes, Thanks! It will work, but why the input overflow the page, do you have any idea? currently its not an requirement, I am just curious

Comment: flex is a one directional flow which can be either horizontal or vertical but there is flex-wrap to break items into multi line

Answer (score 2):

### Not what you want but you can do.

A simple basic form which you can use instead of what you're using rn.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.form-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-container svg {
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  fill: #0071e3;
}

.form-container form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-container h3,
.form-container input {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif, system-ui;
}

.form-container h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container input {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
}

.form-container input:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-container">
  <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M12 2C6.579 2 2 6.579 2 12s4.579 10 10 10 10-4.579 10-10S17.421 2 12 2zm0 5c1.727 0 3 1.272 3 3s-1.273 3-3 3c-1.726 0-3-1.272-3-3s1.274-3 3-3zm-5.106 9.772c.897-1.32 2.393-2.2 4.106-2.2h2c1.714 0 3.209.88 4.106 2.2C15.828 18.14 14.015 19 12 19s-3.828-.86-5.106-2.228z"></path>
    </svg>
  <form class="basic-form">
    <h3>My Account</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added just this code to your CSS/SCSS file:

```css
@media (max-width: 422px) {
    .profile-details {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
 }
```

And it works fine under resolution 422px. you can set any other `max-width` according to your need. I also removed the width of `.inputText`, because it works without that. here is my whole CSS code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: 'segoe ui';
  }
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .myAccount-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-img img {
    width: auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-img img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
  .myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-img, .myAccount-wrapper .myAccount-section .account-form {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  .profile-details {
    display: flex;
  }
  input:focus ~ .floating-label, input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label {
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0px 0 0 15px;
  }
  .profile-name {
    position: relative;
  }
  .inputText {
    font-size: 14px;
    /* width: 200px; */
    height: 35px;
  }
  .floating-label {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 422px) {
    .profile-details {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```